# Column method in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, repeater

I can't find what the column method is actually doing in the docs. Does someone know what it's really doing?

Here is my code:

```
var phoneNameColumn = element.all(by.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
  var query = element(by.model('query'));

  function getNames() {
    return phoneNameColumn.map(function(elm) {
      return elm.getText();
    });
  }

  query.sendKeys('tablet'); //let's narrow the dataset to make the test assertions shorter

  expect(getNames()).toEqual([
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
    "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122"
  ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`column()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) is basically a convenience method to get the columns from a repeater by binding. If you imagine a table formed by a repeater, columns would correspond to your model fields, rows - to model instances.

For example, if you want to get all book name elements from the repeater:

```
element.all(by.repeater('book in library').column('book.name'));
```

You can also get a single book name element in a specific row:

```
element(by.repeater('book in library').row(0).column('book.name'));
```